# Returning a JSON array in Akka Http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have an Akka HTTP server with routing defined like this:

```
case class FooResults(results: Seq[Tuple2[String, Tuple2[Double, Double]]])

object MainApp extends App with JsonSupport {

  ...

  lazy val routes: Route =
    pathPrefix("foo") {
      pathEnd {
        get {
          entity(as[String]) { str =>
          val results =
            (fooActor ? Foo(str)).mapTo[FooResults]
          complete(results)
      }
    }
  }
}
...
```

And in the class I have injected the implicit json support:

```
trait JsonSupport extends SprayJsonSupport {
  import DefaultJsonProtocol._
  implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat1(FooResults)
}
```

Somehow sbt still reports with

```
Type mismatch - FooResults with ToResponseMashallable
```

Anyone had similar problems? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing `FooResult.results` field type to `Seq[(String, (Double, Double)]` ?

Comment: Isn't this the same thing? It's basically a syntactic sugar for Tuple2.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself. It was because there're two SprayJsonSupport classes in my project:

```
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport
```

Now obviously the latter is the correct one. Guess along the way since both Scala and Akka are evolving (fast), sometimes it becomes confusing with the namespaces and classes.